# Xamarin Forms Maps iOS bounds - show all pins on the screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Im using Xamarin Forms Maps, and I want to have the same feature on iOS as I have on Android devices - show all pins on the screen (appropriate position and zoom)

What Im looking is "Bounds" property, but that I only found on XF.GoogleMaps which nuget I dont use.

for Android in my custom renderer I pout LatLngBounds class and made a builder, thats works just fine, but on iOS I didnt find a solution.

Thanks

**UPDATE #1:**
Is this a right method in iOS renderer to put ShowAnnotations? And how to re-pack it to MkAnnotation from Pin model?

```
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
                nativeMap.ZoomEnabled = true;
               
                nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

                //MKAnnotation an = formsMap.CustomPins;
                var numberOfPins = formsMap.CustomPins.Count;
                MKAnnotation[] anotationArray = new MKAnnotation[numberOfPins];

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPins; i++)
                {
                    anotationArray[0].Coordinate = customPins.ElementAt(0).Position...
                }
                foreach (var pin in formsMap.CustomPins)
                {

                }
              
                nativeMap.ZoomEnabled = true;
                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
                nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            }
        }
```

Comment: set the Region property

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `ShowAnnotations` on your `MKMapView`.

You pass in the array of pins (`annotations`) that you wish the map to center and zoom to to able all those pins to the shows at the same time:

```
yourMapView.ShowAnnotations (new [] { pin }, false);
```

Apple Docs: [`showAnnotations:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452309-showannotations?language=objc)

Xamarin Docs: [`ShowAnnotations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/MapKit.MKMapView.ShowAnnotations?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Comment: Thanks, could you post a solution where I transforming customPin to MkAnnotation? Because I need an array for method `ShowAnnotation(new MkAnnotation[]..)` please see my updated question

Comment: @Stefan0309 on the MKMapView instance (your `nativeMap`) there is an `Annotations` property that you can use to retrieve the `IMKAnnotation[]` of all the "custom pins"

Comment: the method ShowAnnotations doesnt unzoom the map in order to preview all pins. I will start a bounty for this question, however we can disscuss more on the implementation code